# How to create ZipArchive object from byte[] C#

Tags: c#, arrays, zip, archive

I have an archive, stored in DB as byte array. I should take it and get inner files for some further processing. But I've got an error while creating `ZipArchive` object:

```
System.IO.InvalidDataException: End of Central Directory record could not be found.
```

My source code:

```
// Zip-archive file
byte[] archiveBytes = dbContext. ... .Select(x => x.Archive).First();

// Representing byte[] as MemoryStream
using (MemoryStream archiveStream = new MemoryStream(archiveBytes))
{
    // Trying to create ZipArchive object from MemoryStream. It brings an ERROR
    using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(archiveStream, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
    {
        // Getting the files from archive
        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe manually extract the archive from the DB and see if you can access it?
It might be corrupt .

Comment: Check, what is `archiveBytes.Length`, what is the size  in the Db, and maybe: what should it be?

Comment: your code it correct. your byte array has either the wrong format or is corrupted

Comment: Thanks for help, the file in DB was corrupted